# Will search engines still see the meta description of my site if I use a php variable for it?

Tags: php, search-engines, meta-description

I am following the procedure described [on this page](http://www.apaddedcell.com/how-automatically-include-your-header-navigation-and-footer-every-page) for including a common header on every page of a website, which uses PHP.

After describing how to include one page in another using PHP, the author then describes how to deal with information that might vary from page to page.

I have included an image of the relevant section below:

> [image]

My question is, if I set up my website this way, will Google (or other search engines) see the meta description of the page `index.php` as `<?php echo $page_description: ?>`, as `Description of this page`, or just not see it at all?

Comment: Why was this question downvote-worthy?

Comment: Related: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/38506/does-browser-understand-php/38508

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Search engines, just like every other user, only see the output of your scripts. Not the source code.

FYI, [meta tags do not affect your rankings](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6/do-meta-keywords-have-any-impact-on-ranking-algorithms).

Comment: Ah, I see - thanks for your help, I'm still very much a novice with this. I did read that meta keywords are rarely used anymore, but the meta description is (at least usually) what shows up as Google's "snippet" for the pages on my site, which is mildly useful.